# Can get Rotativa to Render HTML as PDF

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rotativa

I am using Latest Version of Rotativa.

```
return new Rotativa.PartialViewAsPdf("ExportGuestReportPDF_PrintView", items) { FileName = "Guest Report.pdf" };
```

I am using above code to generate `PDF` file, above code flushed the `PDF` generated file to client/browser. But what i want is `HTML` to be rendered as `PDF` in another `Tab`.

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean open the generated pdf in another tab, try this:

```
return new Rotativa.PartialViewAsPdf("ExportGuestReportPDF_PrintView", items);
```